# Set every new order with woocommerce on hold

Tags: woocommerce

For a specific woocommerce project, I need to set every new order on hold.
It needs to go through that before processing payment.

Do you guys know a hook to do that? I tried many different things, that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order' );
function custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order( $order_id ) {
    global $woocommerce;
     if ( !$order_id )
        return;
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $order->update_status( 'on-hold' );
}
```

This is the standard way of doing it. Not sure if it still works with 2.2, but you didn't specify your WooCommerce version.